# Why is Auth::attempt always returns false in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have this code:

```
 public function postLogin(Request $request) {


    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('users/dashboards');
    }else{
        return redirect('/')->withInput()->with('message', 'Login Failed');
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
  Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Home']);
  Route::post('post-login', ['as' => 'post_login', 'uses' => 'HomeController@postLogin']);

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'user'], function(){
    Route::get('dashboards', ['as' => 'dashboards', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getDashBoards']);
  });
```

I don't know why it always return false. I'm testing if the user is authenticated or not. If I use `Auth::check()` it returns `false` but if I use `Auth::guests` it return `true`. I'm too confused in middleware. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Maybe you're supplying bad credentials all the time. Did you check what the values of username and password are when you fail the authentication? Also, what is confusing you with middleware? The way it works or why it exists?

Comment: No im supplying it with good credentials that is in my database but still no luck. And my password is not `hashed`

Comment: We don't have sufficient info to help you at all. So you have non-hashed password in the database, you supply the "correct" credentials (according to you) but - you do realize that Laravel's `Auth` uses hashed passwords?

Comment: You should hash your password even you just doing testing for the credentials.

Comment: Yes, even if it is hashed or not it will still return true. Because if I hash my passwords. I will compare the inputted password with hashed save in my database with `Hash::check()` method

Comment: Yes It meets my validation rule. I don't include that in my question because it passes. I think it's the problem here is my `Auth::attempt`

Comment: Your password stored in the database is not hashed?

Comment: Yes it is not hashed. And as well as my $request in my inputted fields.

Comment: Auth::attempt  function hashes your  input password --  hence its trying to check with  Input hashPassword  to DB non hash password - error  - try  hashing  your db password , then input non hashed password

Comment: Nope. I hashed my password and still got nothing. It returns false

Comment: what  hash Method did you  use ?

Comment: Hash::make() then I use Hash

Comment: or Create  user  on tinker  php artisan tinker   $user = new App\User;  $user->name = 'Your Name';  $user->email = 'YOUR@email.com'; $user->password = bcrypt('YOUR PASSWORD'); $user->save();

Comment: You need to hash your password during the registration like $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));. As mentioned by @Mjh, Auth::attempt will convert your request to hashed and compared to the password in database

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) // meaning get your password that is not hashed, hash it, and compare your hashed credential in the database, only the password. That means, your password need to be hashed first in the database. Already solved?

Comment: Already hashed but it's still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error occurs in hasValidCredentials function of `framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php`

```
protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials) {
    return ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
}
```

So just replace return statement with

```
return ! is_null($user) ||
$this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but for anyone reading this *don't* do what he recommends. This is a great example of what not to ever do. This code will let anyone login that has as long as a user object is returned. It doesn't care if the credentials are correct or not.